# How to get started with Facebook SDK 5.0.6?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Just download the thing today and read all tutorials available on their site with no luck.
I did place Facebook.dll from Facebook folder to my BIN, don't know what configurations should be written in web.config?

Any kind of help would be nice...

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have VS 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 and nuget, you might find some of the facebook nuget packages help you get started. Doing a search for facebook in nuget brings up 5 packages that are all 5.0.6. I haven't tried any myself, but it would be where I would start.

Nuget packages will typically put any of the configuration bits into web.config and reference any dlls that they need.

Comment: thanks for input. Seems noone can make the thing to work either using nuget or old fashioned way...

Answer (score 0):

I get an error using nuget and can't get the app to start by copying .dll to /bin and adding some lines in the web.config. Is there a documentation on what settings are needed in web.config? I can't find any reference to that.